Python: Add a trailing slash to the URL but only if the URL doesn't end in a slash already or a file extension
I want, in Python, normalize a URL. My main purpose is to add slash / at the end of the URL if it is not already present but only if the URL doesn't end in a slash already or a file extension (so images, .php ,files pages, etc. aren't affected).
For example, if it is http://www.example.com then it should be converted to http://www.example.com/. But if it is http://www.example.com/image.png then it should not be affected.
To do this, I use this regular expression /([^/.]+)$. Regex demo
But it doesn't work in this python code, start_url  is not modified
import re

start_url = "https://zonetuto.fr"
start_url = re.sub(r'/([^/.]+)$', r'/\1/', start_url)
print(start_url)


zonetuto.fr contains a .. Why did you include . into [^/.]? Remove it, see https://ideone.com/blTEsi

Thank you for your help. It's OK with your answer.

I might be tempted to do start_url = f"{start_url.rstrip('/')}/" unless re is a requirement.

Is your current regex working for http://www.example.com or http://www.example.com/file.jpg ?

Re, "only if the URL doesn't end in a slash already or a file extension." Out of curiosity, what is "file extension?" Are you working with some particular web site or class of web sites for which '.' characters in the path component of a URL mean something? Of course, there are a lot of web sites out there where some .xxx
"extension" at the end of the end of a URL path gives you a clue about what you'll GET from that path, but there's no guarantee that it means anything. Nor is it guaranteed to mean anything if the last path component contains no '.' character at all.

You could handle this by considering how a URL is constructed.
The part of the URL that follows the netloc is known as the path
For example:
https://www.example.com does not have a path
https://www.example.com/ has a path - i.e., just the /
https://www.example.com/banana has a path - i.e., /banana
Therefore you could utilise urllib.parse as follows:
from urllib.parse import urlparse

def normalise(url):
    return url if urlparse(url).path else url + "/"

urls = [
    "https://www.example.com",
    "https://www.example.com/",
    "https://www.example.com/banana"
]

for url in urls:
    print(normalise(url))

Output:
https://www.example.com/
https://www.example.com/
https://www.example.com/banana


Just curious to know what will it do it URL is http://www.example.com/image.png ?

@anubhava It won't do anything with it as per the requirement. Try it and you'll see for yourself

Thanks but should 3rd URL not become https://www.example.com/banana/ ?

@anubhava I suggest you re-read the question

lol :) do you seriously believe I haven't. Even OP provided demo is converting www.mysite.com/doc1/doc2/page to www.mysite.com/doc1/doc2/page/

You may use this regex based solution to add / only when it is not added while ignoring / after URLs with file extensions.
import re

urls = [
   'www.example.com',
   'http://www.example.com',
   'www.example.com/page',
   'http://www.example.com/doc1/doc2/page',
   'http://www.example.com/page/',
   'http://www.example.com/dir1/dir2/file.php',
   'http://www.example.com/file.jpg',
   'www.example.com/file.html',
   'www.example.com/file.doc'
]

rx = re.compile(r'^(?:[^:]+://)?[^/]+(?:(?:/[^/]+)*?/[^/.]+)?$')

for url in urls:
    print(rx.sub(r'\g<0>/', url))

Output:
www.example.com/
http://www.example.com/
www.example.com/page/
http://www.example.com/doc1/doc2/page/
http://www.example.com/page/
http://www.example.com/dir1/dir2/file.php
http://www.example.com/file.jpg
www.example.com/file.html
www.example.com/file.doc

Updated RegEx Demo
RegEx Details:

^: Start
(?:[^:]+://)?: Optionally match scheme part that is followed by a //
[^/]+: Match 1+ of any character except /
(?:: Start non-capture group

(?:/[^/]+)*?: Match a / followed by a match 1+ of any character except /. Repeat this group 0 or more times (lazy)
/: Match a /
[^/.]+: Match 1+ of any character except / and .


)?: End optional non-capture group
$: End


You could do it like this
 url = "https://example.com" 
    
 if url.count("/") == 2:
   url = url + "/"
    
 print(url)

